# Mapping a table column with values that persist on create and update in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column in the table that has string values for:

`arr = ["First Name", "Last Name", "location", "Description"]`

I need to map each of these values to letters sequentially:

`["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

These letters aren't part of the table and aren't defined, but I am leaning toward creating a small hash with the above arr, unless there is a better suggestion?

I need to be able to map each letter to its correspond value in the arr, and when the arr is updated in a view, each letter should correspond in the arr. For example, if the "First Name" is removed from the arr, then the first latter should be "B", or if the "location" is removed, then the new array should be "A", "B", "D". Meaning, on create or update, letters should always be mapped to corresponding values in the arr. I hope I am making sense?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify this bit: *and so when a users creates or updates arr it persist*?

Answer (score 1):

For example  you have

```
arr = ["First Name", "Last Name", "location", "Description"]
arr_hash= Hash.new

and yout have a instance for 
@client =Client.first


hash[0] = []
hash[0] << arr 

hash[1] = []
hash[1] << @client
```

and more....

Answer (score 0):

You can make hash with pairs first, and then remove keys that are not present in updated array.

```
arr = ["First Name", "Last Name", "location", "Description"]
arr2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

result = Hash[arr.zip(arr2)]
# => {"First Name"=>"A", "Last Name"=>"B", "location"=>"C", "Description"=>"D"}

# update original arr like:
arr = ["Last Name", "location", "Description"]

result.delete_if { |k, _| !arr.include?(k) }
# => {"Last Name"=>"B", "location"=>"C", "Description"=>"D"}
```

Comment: Thanks @rastasheep. Not what I needed. Working on other solutions.